# Powershell find non-ASCII characters in text file

Tags: powershell, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to find a way using Powershell Script to do the following.

1. For each line in text file, check if line contains non-ASCII characters
2. If line contains non-ASCII characters, output to separate file
3. If line does not contain non-ASCII characters, skip to next line

By non-ASCII characters, I'm referring to non keyboard characters, e.g. accented characters, characters from another language, etc.

**Sample Data**

```
 - 张伟
 - குழந்தைகளுக்கான பெயர்கள்
 - 日本人の氏名
 - Full Name
 - Léna Rémi
```

**Output Data**

```
 - 张伟
 - குழந்தைகளுக்கான பெயர்கள்
 - 日本人の氏名
 - Léna Rémi
```

I found the regex in other threads to remove non-ASCII characters but I couldn't seem to make it work.

Please help!

** EDIT **
Thanks everyone for the help! I have managed to do what I wanted with the below script.

```
$nonASCII = "[^\x00-\x7F]"
foreach ($_ in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($source)){
    if ($_ -cmatch $nonASCII){
        write-output $_ | out-File $output -append        
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by non-ascii characters? Which encodings are you using? Can you add some sample data with desired outputs?

Comment: @vonPryz I've edited my main thread to further elaborate on what I hope to achieve.

Comment: you can use a negated character class and test for that class. something like `-match '[^0-9a-z]'`. plus, there are supposed to be ways to specify unicode character classes. i can't recall how, tho ... [*blush*]

Comment: Test with regex `^[\x20-\x7e]+$`? That should match characers from `space` to `tilde`. Don't use `[ -~]` insead, unless you want the next maintainer a lot of headache.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I would use -cnotmatch.  There's some funny exceptions otherwise between the capital and small versions of characters.

Comment: @js2010 - i have not run into that ... yet. thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Actually your test works, but the letter i passes as non-ascii in this test:  `echo i I | where { $_ -match '[\u0080-\uffff]' }`.

Answer (score 9):

Define a character set that describes all ASCII characters (code points 32 through 127 == `[\x20-\x7F]`), then negate it with `^` to match any non-ASCII character!

Let's test it against my (non-ASCII) name:

```bsh
PS C:\> 'Mathias R. Jessen' -cmatch '[^\x20-\x7F]'
False
PS C:\> 'Mathias Rørbo Jessen' -cmatch '[^\x20-\x7F]'
True
```

To filter a list of strings, simply use the `-cmatch` operator in filter mode:

```bsh
$strings = 'குழந்தைகளுக்கான பெயர்கள்', 'Boring John Doe', 'Léna Rémi'

$nonASCIIstrings = @($strings) -cmatch '[^\x20-\x7F]'
```

Or if you want to filter along a pipeline, use `Where-Object`:

```bsh
$strings |Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '[^\x20-\x7F]'}
```

Comment: How to do it with a file?

Comment: @mercury `Select-String` allows you to search a file while specifying the encoding: `Select-String -Path file.txt -Encoding Unicode -Pattern '...'`

Answer (score 5):

**The .NET regex engine supports a *direct* expression of the concept "non-ASCII character": `\P{IsBasicLatin}`** (the inverse, i.e. "ASCII character", is `\p{IsBasicLatin}`):

```bash
' - 张伟',
' - குழந்தைகளுக்கான பெயர்கள்',
' - 日本人の氏名',
' - Full Name', 
' - Léna Rémi' -cmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
```

`IsBasicLatin` is an example of a [*named (Unicode) block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks).

The above **requires `-cmatch`**, the case-*sensitive* variant of `-match`,<sup>[1]</sup> the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), to output those input lines (array elements) that contain at least one non-ASCII-range character:

```bash
 - 张伟
 - குழந்தைகளுக்கான பெயர்கள்
 - 日本人の氏名
 - Léna Rémi
```

---

For a *streaming solution* - processing lines read from a file one by one, you can combine `-match` with the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet:

```bash
Get-Content in.txt | 
  Where-Object { $_ -cmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}' } |
  Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 out.txt
```

Note that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) is used to read the file line by line - while `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path in.txt))` works too, it is only necessary if there's a performance problem.

---

<sup>[1] The reason is that with case-*insensitive* matching, the lowercase ASCII `i` and `k` characters are considered *both* inside *and* outside the ASCII block, i.e. `'i' -match '\P{IsBasicLatin}'` and  `'i' -match '\p{IsBasicLatin}'` are *both* `$true`. For an explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023639/45375). Tip of the hat to [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script I have to remove non-ascii characters from an xml file.  Maybe you can use it as a starting point.  I'm removing characters that are not between space and tilde in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and also not tab.  To me, ascii is in the range 0-127.  Get-content takes out the carriage returns and linefeeds.

```
(get-content $args[0]) -replace '[^ -~\t]' | set-content $args[0]
```