# Remove rows that have Non-English characters in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I wanna remove all rows in the text file that have have Non-English characters in Powershell, here is what I've tried so far:

```
Where-Object {( $_ -notlike '[\x00-\x7F]+' ) -or ( $_ -notlike '[\u4e00-\u9fff]')}
```

However, the Asian characters (Japanese, Korean and Russian) are still there and did not got removed, such as the below:

```
多発性硬化
多発性硬化症
다발 경화증
다발성 경화증
ﾀﾊﾂｾｲｺｳｶｼｮｳ
Рассеянный склероз
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `Where-Object {( $_ -notmatch '[\x00-\x7F]' )}`?

Comment: You're confusing -notlike with -notmatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
PS> 'english only', 'mixed 多発性硬化', '多発性硬化', 'mixed склероз', 'склероз'  | 
      Where-Object { $_ -cnotmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}' }

english only
```

- `\p{IsBasicLatin}` matches any ASCII-range character (any character in the 7-bit Unicode code-point range, `0x0 - 0x7f`), and `\P{IsBasicLatin}` is its *negation*, i.e. matches any character *outside* that range.
- `-cnotmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}'` therefore only matches strings that contain *no* non-ASCII characters, in other words: strings that contain *only* ASCII-range characters.

  - Note<sup>Tip of the hat to [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) for the pointer.</sup>:

    - **`-cnotmatch`, the case-*sensitive* variant** of the case-insensitive [`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator is deliberately used, so as to **rule out false positives** that would occur with case-*insensitive* matching, namely with the **lowercase ASCII-range letters `i` and `k`**.
    - The reason is that these characters are *also* considered the lowercase counterparts to *non*-ASCII-range characters, namely `İ` (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE, [`U+0130`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/130)) (as used in Turkic languages), and
      and `K` (KELVIN SIGN, [`U+212A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/212a)); therefore, with case-*insensitive* matching via `-match`, `i` and `k` report `$true` for *both* `\p{IsBasicLatin}` (falling *into* the ASCII block) *and* `\P{IsBasicLatin}` (falling *outside* the ASCII block); that is, *all* of the following expressions return `$true`:

      ```bash
      # !! All return $true; use -cmatch for the expected behavior.
      'i' -match '\p{IsBasicLatin}'; 'i' -match '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
      'k' -match '\p{IsBasicLatin}'; 'k' -match '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
      ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo if you really want to use -notlike, which uses *wildcards*.  This excludes u+0000 - u+007F or u+4e00 - u+9fff.  It ends up not working though.
The file this is saved in would have to support full unicode codepoints, utf8 *with bom* in powershell 5.

```
$mynull = [char]0x00

'多発性硬化',
'多発性硬化症',
'다발 경화증',
'다발성 경화증',
'ﾀﾊﾂｾｲｺｳｶｼｮｳ',
'Рассеянный склероз',
'abc' | where {  $_ -notlike "*[$mynull-⌂]*" -or $_ -notlike '*[一-鿿]*' } 
 

多発性硬化
多発性硬化症
다발 경화증
다발성 경화증
ﾀﾊﾂｾｲｺｳｶｼｮｳ
Рассеянный склероз
abc
```

An example that works.  (I converted $end to hex wrong before.)

```
$beg = [char]0x420
$end = [char]0xff8a

$mystrings = '多発性硬化',
'多発性硬化症',
'다발 경화증',
'다발성 경화증',
'ﾀﾊﾂｾｲｺｳｶｼｮｳ',
'Рассеянный склероз',
'',  # 2 surrogate characters in range
'abc'

$mystrings | where { $_ -cnotlike "*[$beg-$end]*" }

#$mystrings | % { $ints = [int[]][char[]]$_; $ints} | sort
#1056-65418
 

abc
```