# Removing unicode character using Powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode

I have some problems using vlookup in Excel.
I have seen the issue, but I haven't got the solution yes.

I have a huge amount of lines in a txt file, these lines contains Unicode characters.

Example:
This line: 'S0841488.JPG06082014‏‎08.21'
contains those two unicode characters: U+200F U+200E
'S0841488.JPG06082014 U+200F U+200E 08.21.

Please tell me how to remove these unicode characters using Powershell.

Comment: This is a common question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792387/powershell-find-non-ascii-characters-in-text-file

Answer (score 14):

If you want to **remove all characters that fall outside the *ASCII* range** (Unicode code-point range `U+0000` - `U+007F`):

```bash
# Removes any non-ASCII characters from the LHS string,
# which includes the problematic hidden control characters.
'S0841488.JPG06082014‏‎08.21' -creplace '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
```

The solution uses `-creplace`, the case-*sensitive* variant<sup>[1]</sup> of the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), with the negated form (`\P`) of the Unicode [block name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks) `IsBasicLatin`, which refers to the ASCII sub-range of Unicode. In short: `\P{IsBasicLatin}` matches any non-ASCII character, and since no replacement string is specified, effectively *removes* it; combined with `-creplace` invariably replacing *all* matches in the input string, all non-ASCII characters are removed.

Note:

- If you instead want to **remove characters outside the *[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)* range** (Unicode code-point range `U+0000` - `U+00FF`), which includes accented characters such as `é`, use the following:

  ```bash
  # Removes non ISO-8859-1 characters.
  # -> 'Café £', i.e. '€' and '—' (em dash) were removed, 
  #    but 'é' and '£' were retained. 
  'Café €—£' -creplace '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]'
  ```

  - **Caveat**: ISO-8859-1 is *largely, but not fully* identical to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), one notably consequence of which is the absence of `€`, as demonstrated above. You can manually include the missing characters in the above character-set expression (`[...]`) for full Windows-1252 compatibility: `€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`
- Given the correlation with Unicode code-point ranges, you can also use the **more concise, but less descriptive solutions**:

  - `... -replace '[^\x00-\x7F]` for retaining only ASCII-range chars.
  - `... -replace '[^\x00-\xFF]` for retaining only ISO-88591-1-range chars.

---

You can **verify** that this effectively removes the (invisible) LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK, [`U+200E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e) and RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK, [`U+200F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f) characters from your string with the help of the **`Debug-String`** function, which is available as [an MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1):

```bash
# Download and define the Debug-String function.
# NOTE: 
#  I can personally assure you that doing this is safe, but you
#  you should always check the source code first.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex


# Visualize the existing non-ASCII-range characters
'S0841488.JPG06082014‏‎08.21' | Debug-String -UnicodeEscapes

# Remove them and verify that they're gone.
'S0841488.JPG06082014‏‎08.21' -replace '\P{IsBasicLatin}' | Debug-String -UnicodeEscapes
```

The above yields the following:

```
S0841488.JPG06082014`u{200f}`u{200e}08.21
S0841488.JPG0608201408.21
```

Note the visualization of the invisible control characters as `` `u{200f} `` and `` `u{200e} `` in the original input string, and how they are no longer present after applying the `-replace` operation.

In PowerShell (Core) 7+ (but not Windows PowerShell), such Unicode escape sequences can also be used in expandable strings, i.e. inside double-quoted string literals (e.g., `` "Hi`u{21}" `` expands to verbatim `Hi!`) - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023639/45375) for an explanation of why case-*sensitive* matching must be used.

Despite the operator being case-sensitive, the inherently case-insensitive `\P{L}` regex block-name construct still excludes lowercase letters too (whereas `\P{Lu}` / `\P{Ll}`would only exclude uppercase / lowercase letters).</sup>

Comment: `'"Véronique & “Cheris"' -creplace '\P{IsBasicLatin}'` also removes `é`, which is a [valid](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E9) Latin character.  Is there a way to keep this charachter?

Comment: @DarkLite1, use `'"Véronique & “Cheris"' -creplace '[^\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]'`

Comment: @DarkLite1, please see my update, and note the pitfall re ISO-8859-1 vs. Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0):

If they are written as you say as 'U+200F' and 'U+200E' so basic replace will do the work. Only required to make escape character before +. Because it has a special meaning in regex.

Regex explanation:

\s - Means whitespace.

? - It maybe exists maybe not.

\ - Before + is an escape character.

[EF] - It means letter E or letter F.

('|.$) - single-quote or dot at the end.

```
# Path to your file and new file where no unicode characters.
$Path = "C:\JustForExample\FileThatContainsThisLines.txt"
$NewPath = "C:\JustForExample\FileThatContainsThisLines2.txt"

# Getting content of file.
$content = Get-Content -Path $Path

# Removing unicode characters.
$newContent = $content -replace "\s?U\+200[EF]\s?"

# For removing quot and dot at the end.
$newContent = $newContent -replace "('|\.$)" 

# Saving content to new Path.
# If you need to replace them inside the file, so just change NewPath to Path.
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $NewPath
```

So replace simple should remove what is a match to that pattern.

Comment: Hi Puzo

Thank you - but - I´m sorry, it doesn´t work as intended.

I use this one URL for viewing the Unicode characers:
https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php
 - and after running the script, the characters haven´t been removed.
The result is:
S0841488.JPG06082014‏‎ U+200F U+200E 08.21.

Comment: Hmmm... 
My main issue because I can't reproduce it to check why this is not working.

Maybe you can try that convert all content to UTF8, and then they become visible.

$MyRawString = Get-Content -Raw $Path
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($NewPath, $MyRawString, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)

Can you share some example file?

Comment: The desire is to remove the actual Unicode characters from the strings - something like `U+200F` is just a _visualization_ of those characters, which themselves are _invisible_. If you copy and paste the string following the phrase "This line: " from the question, you'll get a string that contains these hidden characters.

Comment: Removing all characters that fall outside the ASCII range using this command:
$newContent = $content -replace '\P{IsBasicLatin}'

Though, it creates a new error: ALL 'I' (capital i) is removed.