# Powershell string concatenation mystery

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a variable with a string but get always a space a inbetween

```
[xml] $buildConfig = Get-Content $paths_target_file_path
$ver = $buildConfig.Project.PropertyGroup.LibVersion
$ver = $ver -replace "\s+",""
$version = "V"+$ver
Write-Host "Downloading LIB version: $version"
```

The above output is *Downloading Lib version: V 1.2.11*
i.e. a space between V and 1.2.11 despite replacing any whitespace character

Markus

Comment: are you certain that the apparent space is actually a standard space? there are other chars that look like a space. one way to test would be to feed `$Ver` to `Format-Hex` and see what the actual char codes are.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: `\s` also covers Unicode variations of the ASCII space char. (e.g., ([`U+00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0), the no-break space) - do you know of any character that _presents_ like a space yet isn't matched by `\s`? `Format-Hex` isn't an option in Windows PowerShell, because it represents any non-ASCII chars. as `3f`==  literal `?`. In PowerShell Core it shows _the bytes that make up the UTF-8 encoding_ of non-ASCII characters, which can be confusing. There is no straightforward built-in solution; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328388/45375).

Comment: I bet `$ver` is not of the type string.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce it anymore after changing my xml file :-( . I 'll come back if it reappears.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The implication is that `$ver` contains an *array* of strings, not just a single string:

- The [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) can operate on *arrays* as the LHS, in which case the operation is applied to *each element* of the array, and the results are again returned *as an array*.
- When PowerShell *stringifies* an array - such as when using explicit string concatenation with `+` or in implicitly inside an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`) -  it joins the array elements with a *space* between them.

Therefore, your symptom implies that `$ver` is not a single string, but a *2-element array* whose first element is the *empty string*:

A simple demonstration:

```sh
$ver = ('', ' foo ') -replace '\s+'

'V' + $ver
```

The above yields verbatim `V foo`

To use the *first non-empty* element of the `$ver` array, use the following:

```
'V' + ($ver -ne '')[0]  # -> 'Vfoo'
```

Comment: Right, I think If OP tries `[string]$ver = $buildConfig.Project.PropertyGroup.LibVersion` he would see the expected result. Similar to `$ver = [string]('', ' foo ') -replace '\s+'` from your example. Excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon, but your command wouldn't prevent the space. Try `[string] $ver = '', 'foo'; "[$ver]"`

Comment: Right, I mean something like `[string]($buildConfig.Project.PropertyGroup.LibVersion) -replace '\s+'` from OP's question. I think that should work, its hard to tell tho without inspecting the object.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, if the LHS of the `-replace` operation is an array, so is the return value, so the `-replace` makes no difference.

Comment: I understand what you mean but `$ver = [string]('', ' foo ') -replace '\s+'` gives me the expected results which is why I assume that from OP's question `$ver = [string]($buildConfig.Project.PropertyGroup.LibVersion) -replace '\s+'` should also give the expected result.

Comment: That's because the `[string]` cast has higher precedence than the `-replace` operation - see the conceptual [about_Operator_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) help topic. The real test is (note the extra parentheses): `$ver = [string] (('', ' foo ') -replace '\s+'); "[$ver]"`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I see what you're saying now. Yes, if you force the LHS array to a space-separated string first and then _remove all spaces_, you'll get the desired result too, but, for conceptual clarity, I suggest isolating the single array element of interest first.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, but, to be clear: the version with the _type constraint_, from your _first_ comment, would _not_ work, because the `[string]` cast is then applied _after_ the `-replace` operation (to recap: `[string] $ver = ('', 'foo') -replace '\s+'; "[$ver]"`)

Comment: Yeah you're totally right, from my first comment, the first example would not work I realized that later after trying.