# Simple way to convert txt file from UTF-8 to ASCII

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, ascii, txt

I am trying to convert just one file from UTF-8 to ASCII. I found the following script online, and it creates the `Out-File` but it does not change the encoding to ASCII. Why is this not working?

```
Get-Content -Path "File/Path/to/file.txt" | Out-File -FilePath "File/Path/to/processed.txt" -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Because at the bottom of the text file it says UTF-8. I was under the impression that at the bottom of a txt file it would say ASCII (ANSI) if it was ASCII

Comment: As an aside: ANSI is a different (group of) encoding(s), each of them also a _superset_ of ASCII, as UTF-8 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**`-Encoding ASCII` *does* work, though your editor's GUI may still report the resulting file as UTF-8-encoded**, for the reasons explained below.

---

First, a **general caveat**:

- If your input file also contains non-ASCII-range characters, they will be transliterated to *verbatim `?`*, i.e. you'll potentially lose information.
- Conversely, if your input files are UTF-8-encoded but do *not* contain non-ASCII characters, they in effect already *are* ASCII-encoded files; see below.

**[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding is a *subset* of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** encoding (except that ASCII encoding never involves a [*BOM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

- Therefore, **any (BOM-less) file composed exclusively of bytes representing ASCII characters is by definition *also* a valid UTF-8 file**.

Modern editors default to *BOM-less* UTF-8; that is, if a file doesn't start with a BOM, they assume that it is UTF-8-encoded, and that's what their GUIs reflect - even if a given file happens to be composed of ASCII characters only.

---

To **verify that your output file is indeed only composed of ASCII characters**, use the following:

```sh
# This should return $false; '\P{IsBasicLatin}' matches any NON-ASCII character.
(Get-Content -Raw File/Path/to/processed.txt) -cmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
```

For an explanation of this test, especially with respect to needing to use `-cmatch`, the case-*sensitive* variant of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023639/45375).

---

A complete example:

```sh
# Write a string that contains non-ASCII characters to a
# file with -Encoding Ascii
# The resulting fill will contain 1 line, with content 'caf?'
# That is, the "é" character was "lossily" transliterated to (ASCII) "?"
'café' | Out-File -Encoding Ascii temp.txt

# Examining the file for non-ASCII characters now indicates that
# there are none, i.e, $false is returned.
(Get-Content -Raw temp.txt) -cmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}'
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! That update did return `processed.txt` as false this time around. Out of curiosity, I ran `(Get-Content -Raw File/Path/to/file.txt) -cmatch '\P{IsBasicLatin}'` on the original file (`file.txt`), and that also returned false. Why would this be?

Comment: @Crimp, that implies that the original file contained no non-ASCII characters either (though, at least in principle, it could use a different character encoding, such as UtF-16LE ("Unicode"), which PowerShell automatically supports if such a file starts with a BOM). Btw, it's both `i` and `k` characters that cause problems with `-match`; you can find an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023639/45375).