PowerShell, How to replace or remove extended characters from text file
I have the following text in a file
Title: ├® Standard

Title: ├® Roarinc

Title: EaglesÔÇÖ Nest.

I want PowerShell to normalise this by removing things like "├®" and "ÔÇÖ", but to of course leave things like "." and ":". I think the "ÔÇÖ" is supposed to be a "'" (this text was extracted from image PNG files), as I think that should be "Eagles' Nest" though I'm not sure. I guess that this is to do with encoding or something. Whenever I try to do a replace, I get an error:
-replace "ÔÇÖ", ""

Like this:
At C:\Users\roysu\OneDrive\0_Scripts_PowerShell\Extract-All-Pages-From-Images-with-Tesseract.ps1:122 char:51
+ $processedContent = $processedContent -replace "â”œÂ®", ""
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'œÂ®", ""
$processedContent = $processedContent -replace "' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\roysu\OneDrive\0_Scripts_PowerShell\Extract-All-Pages-From-Images-with-Tesseract.ps1:123 char:53
+ $processedContent = $processedContent -replace " \| ", ""
+                                                     ~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At C:\Users\roysu\OneDrive\0_Scripts_PowerShell\Extract-All-Pages-From-Images-with-Tesseract.ps1:124 char:49
+ $processedContent = $processedContent -replace "Ã”Ã‡Ã–", ""
+                                                 ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Ã”Ã‡Ã–"' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\roysu\OneDrive\0_Scripts_PowerShell\Extract-All-Pages-From-Images-with-Tesseract.ps1:124 char:56
+ $processedContent = $processedContent -replace "Ã”Ã‡Ã–", ""
+                                                        ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

How can I remove this kind of text. The full script would be incredibly unhelpful here as it does other things, I need to focus on just doing one thing, how do we replace / remove extended characters that are in a text file? Even better, how do I remove all such extended characters from the text file (this would probably be the most suitable, as they are not useful at all to me)?

This works for me: -replace '[├®ÔÇÖ]'

get-content -encoding utf8

Powershell find non-ASCII characters in text file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792387/powershell-find-non-ascii-characters-in-text-file/61798375#61798375

The issue where you dealing with is that the smart quotes are interpreted by the syntax parser as normal "dump" quotes. This means that you either have to escape them (using a backtick: `) or enclose your string in single quotes instead (see quoting rules):
'Myâ”œÂ®String' -replace "â`”œÂ®"
MyString

or:
'Myâ”œÂ®String' -replace 'â”œÂ®'
MyString


Note that there is no need to define to <substitute> (as , "") for the -Replace operator if you want to remove the specific <regular-expression> part of the input string.

The second error:
Unexpected token 'œÂ®", ""
$processedContent = $processedContent -replace "' in expression or statement.
is actually caused by the first issue as the first command line includes the next PowerShell command up to the next double quote, leaving something like  \| ", " as a bogus pipeline command.
Anyways, to remove all the non-ASC characters, you might consider a more generic regular expression to remove everything that isn't ASCII: '[^\x20-\x7F]'.
'Title: EaglesÔÇÖ Nest.' -replace '[^\x20-\x7F]'
Title: Eagles Nest.

Side note:
To properly test and display the concerned characters mentioned in the question in your console, you might want to change the input/output encoding of your console:
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding =
                New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding

For more details on the console input/output encoding, see this helpful answer from mklement0

This is interesting, yes, removing everything non-ASCII is in line with my needs. I was also searching and saw that converting the file content to plain ASCII to strip away any non-ASCII characters might be done by filtering out any characters that are not part of the basic ASCII character set (values 0–127). $myContent = Get-Content "myfile.txt" -Raw; $asciiContent = $myContent | ForEach-Object {     -join ($_.ToCharArray() | Where-Object { [int][char]$_ -lt 128 }) }. When you do -replace '[^\x20-\x7F]', is that equivalent? (your technique looks easier).

Not exactly, apart from the fact this would be more expensive as it requires you to rebuild the string by joining all the characters again), there are also control characters (everything below a space -\x20-,  as a tab, CR, LF, Esc, etc.) that you probably also want to remove.

Good points; if the intent is just to eliminate / match non-ASCII-range characters while also keeping ASCII-range control characters, such as tabs and newlines, \P{IsBasicLatin} / \p{IsBasicLatin} can be used, as a more readable alternative to [^\x00-\x7F] / [\x00-\x7F]. However, an unexpected pitfall with the former is the need to use the case-sensitive operators, -creplace / -cmatch, as explained in this answer.


To complement iRon's helpful answer:

I guess that this is to do with encoding or something.

Indeed, your problem is one of character encoding, and it is best to solve it at that level:
tl;dr

Either: Prevent misinterpretation of UTF-8 output from an external program by setting [Console]::OutputEncoding to UTF-8 first, before capturing output:
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

some.exe ... > file.txt

# Consider restoring the original encoding; omitted for brevity


Or: Fix your mis-decoded strings / files after the fact:
# Get the *byte* representation of the string in the mistakenly used
# encoding, which restores the original UTF-8 bytes, then re-read
# the bytes as UTF-8.
[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
  [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(
    (Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw file.txt)
  )
) |
  Set-Content -Encoding utf8 -NoNewLine file_fixed.txt     



Read on for an explanation.

Background information

Your symptom suggests that your output was created by a console application, i.e. an external program that unconditionally outputs UTF-8-encoded text.

It further suggests that when you made PowerShell capture that output in a file, the UTF-8 output was misinterpreted as code page 850 output, resulting in the artifacts in your file such as ÔÇÖ, which is a misreading of the 3-byte UTF-8 encoding of the ’ (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, U+2019) character as 3 individual code page 850 characters.

When PowerShell captures output from an external program on Windows, it uses the code page associated with the legacy system locale's OEM code page by default to decode the raw program output, such as code page 437 on US-English systems, or code page 850 on Western European systems (as in your case).

Perhaps surprisingly, it also does this when sending external-program output to a file, because the captured output is first decoded into a .NET string, and then re-encoded for file output (note that this implies that the original encoding is not preserved).

The only exception is the use of >, the redirection operator operator in PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4+, which now does capture an external program's raw byte output as-is.


Therefore, the solution (that works in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7) is to (temporarily) set the console code page to match the character encoding used by the console application of interest, i.e. to 65001, which is UTF-8. Because .NET caches encodings, chcp 65001 does not work, unfortunately, but the following does:
# Do this *before* running external programs that produce UTF-8 output.
# You may want to restore the original encoding afterwards.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# Now run your external program and capture its output with >, for instance; e.g. 
#   some.exe ... > file.txt


The longer statement in iRon's answer fully switches the current console window to UTF-8, including ensuring that when PowerShell sends text via the pipeline to an external program, it is UTF-8-encoded too (something that PowerShell 7 now does by default).




If rerunning the external program is not an option and you have to deal with already mis-decoded strings, you can alternatively fix the encoding problem after the fact as follows:
$misDecodedString = 'EaglesÔÇÖ Nest.'

# The encoding that the string was mis-decoded as.
$oemEnc = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850)

# Get the *byte* representation of the string in the mistakenly used
# encoding, which restores the original UTF-8 bytes, then re-read
# the bytes as UTF-8.
[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
  $oemEnc.GetBytes($misDecodedString)
)


The result is Eagles’ Nest., as desired, and you can save this string to a UTF-8-encoded file with Set-Content -Encoding utf8, for instance; note that in Windows PowerShell this yields a UTF-8 file with BOM, whereas in PowerShell 7 it is BOM-less (and the -Encoding utf8 part can be omitted there, given that BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent PowerShell 7 default; conversely, if you do want a BOM in PowerShell 7, use -Encoding utf8BOM; if you do not want a BOM in Windows PowerShell, workarounds are required - see this answer).



